# Matching entire, multiline pattern, multiple times but not if match contains string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Imagine I have this text (I realise using regex to parse HTML is not the correct solution...)

```
 <div><p>HELLO1</p>
 <span>SPIDER</span></div>
 <div><p>HELLO2</p>
 <span>CHEESE</span></div>
 <div><p>HELLO3</p>
 <span>BANANA</span></div>
```

I want to match text inside the `<p>` and `<span>` respectively (this is a contrived example)

I can achieve that by using:

`/<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<span>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<\/div>/gsmi`

However, I don't want to match if the text inside the span is `CHEESE`.
Ive tried to use a negative lookahead like so:

`/<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<span>((?!CHEESE).*?)<\/span>.*?<\/div>/gsmi`

However, that now matches the wrong thing as the pattern matches to `HELLO2` and `BANANA` where I want `HELLO3` and `BANANA`

I realise this is because Im using `.*?` but this is required for the real life solution.

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/h4YgDm/3

How can I match, a whole pattern only but still spanning multiple lines?

Comment: You have no <p> tag in your example.

Comment: @ReymartBetana Thanks - I refactored example, whilst writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine sent me this answer, which does what I want:

https://regex101.com/r/h4YgDm/8

Regex: `(?:(?:<div><p>(\w*)<\/p>\s)(?!<span>CHEESE<\/span>)(?:<span>(\w*)<\/span>)<\/div>)`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want in two steps. First, extract the `div` elements which meet the criteria (ie. no CHEESE) like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8hAp5/1)):

```
<div>(?:(?!CHEESE).)*?<\/div>
```

Second, select the content between `p` and `span` tags as two groups ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8hAp5/2)):

```
(?<=<p>)(.*?)(?=<\/p>)(?:.*?)(?<=<span>)(.*?)(?=<\/span>)
```

Comment: Is there anyway this can done in one step? Perhaps using back references?

Comment: Not as far as I know.